# Responsive styles not applying for window resizing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I need to design a responsive website that is responsive also when the browser window is resized.

I have added the following code in the head tag:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

And i have included the following styles:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1500px)" href="style.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="mobile.css" />
```

However when i resize my browser window to a width of less than 480 pixels, still the document is styled using style.css whereas it should have been styled by mobile.css

What am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`max-device-width` refers to your device resolution, not the window width size, that is `min-width` or `max-width` see [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml) for better understanding.

`device-width` are used when you want to target mobile devices but not desktop small resized windows.

So, if you want your `mobile.css` be used for mobile devices with screen resolution width less than `481px` and also include desktop browsers windows resized to less than `481px` then replace:

```
(max-device-width: 480px)
```

for:

```
(max-width: 480px)
```

in your `mobile.css` media query rule.